# XAMPP - php_body_write could not be located in c:\xampp\php\ext\php_mssql.dll (Windows)

Tags: windows, apache, xampp

I've inherited an XAMPP installation and need to use PHP to connect to am MSSQL database.

I un-commented `extension=php_mssql.dll` in php.ini and had to download the file and put it into C:\xampp\php\ext manually.

I then had to download `ntwdblib.dll` and put it into the c:\Windows folder

I'm now getting the following error when I restart Apache via XAMPP control:

```
httpd.exe - Entry Point Not Found
The procedure entry point php_body_write could not be located in the dynamic link library C;\xampp\php\ext\php_mssql.dll
```

Any ideas what to check next? I really do not know what the php_body_write thing means.

Thanks.

**Update:**

I think this may be related, it looks like XAMPP was built specifically without MSSQL. I found this in the phpinfo:

```
cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--disable-isapi" "--enable-debug-pack" **"--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql"** "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient11\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--disable-static-analyze" "--with-pgo"
```

Can I rebuild or is reinstalling really the only option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem one, just reinstalled XAMPP and everything work fine.

Comment: thanks, I'd rather try and fix it without reinstalling as it already has things running on it and I'd rather not go down that route. Thank you.